# How can i dispose IDisposable when it is declared in a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

```
SendEmail("message", "subject", new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path1), new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path2));
```

How can i dispose the last two attachments in the parameter? Will it dispose itself when done?

Comment: i think yes if there is a destructor defined in that class which disposes the resources.

Comment: No no no - the GC ***never*** ever calls `.Dispose()`. You ***must*** explicitly call it yourself.

Comment: yes. if its called in destructor. should check the source code. @Enigmativity

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - Yes, you're right. If an object has a finalizer ***and*** the finalizer calls `.Dispose()` then (almost always) `.Dispose()` will be called (but not always - as finalization is non-deterministic).

Comment: Note that Finalizers shouldn't call `Dispose()` - [they should call an overloaded version `Dispose(bool)` passing false, and `Dispose()` should call `Dispose(bool)` passing true.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: In this case, the class `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` does ***not*** have a finalizer, so the GC ***can not*** trigger a call to `.Dispose()`. @dotctor

Comment: @dotctor - Please don't delete comments when they affect future readers ability to understand the conversation.

Comment: I deleted it because it was first comment and may affect readers because it was incorrect and maybe they don't read the whole conversation here and I was unable to edit it. @Enigmativity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because you don't have a reference to them.

Move them outside the method call:

```
using (var attachment1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path1))
using (var attachment2 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path2))
{
    SendEmail("message", "subject", attachment1, attachment2);
}
```